# How to convert a txt file to yml file by bash command?

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a txt file it has some contents, and i want to convert it into yml format using linux commands.

Sample Txt File

```
mac
linux
windows
```

And i want following output. like i want to add "os" keyword and convert this to yml by linux command.

```
os:
   - mac
   - linux
   - windows
```

Can Anyone try me to get this, Thanks

Comment: What is the `yq` version you have? Post the output of `yq --version`

Comment: yq version 4.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), you could just read the input text file contents as a raw string and then split on a space.

Note that, this is fragile, because it doesn't hold well when your string contents contain a space themselves.

```sh
yq e '{"os": split(" ")}' yaml
```